# MongoDB updateOne creates duplicate field instead of updating existing field

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the updateOne method in MongoDB to update a field in a document. However, instead of updating the existing field, it creates a duplicate field with the new value. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$collection->updateOne(
    ['property_id' => $id],
    ['$set' => ['billboard_img' => $imageUrl]]
);
```

I've confirmed that the property_id field is correctly matching the document, and the code is executed without any errors. However, the result is a duplicate field with the new value instead of updating the existing field. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.

I've also tried using the $unset operator to remove the field before updating it, but that didn't solve the issue either:

```
$collection->updateOne(
    ['property_id' => $id],
    ['$unset' => ['billboard_img' => '']]
);

$collection->updateOne(
    ['property_id' => $id],
    ['$set' => ['billboard_img' => $imageUrl]]
);
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as duplicated field, as a JSON can not have two identical fields. There must be a difference between the field names, creating the issue. Possibly a space or a typo...

Comment: @nimrodserok oh, thnaks for pointing out my mistake! There was a in my insert documents code (billborad_img instead of billboard_img)...i literally overlooked that thinking that something is surely wrong with my code!Thanks again!

Comment: There is such a thing as a duplicate field, because the database does BSON not JSON. Most drivers disallow this so it is difficult to create. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-allows-multiple-keys-with-the-same-name/754/2) for discussion and a link to documentation. In any case looks like that wasn't the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in insert document code, this update code is fine!